# How to develop a payment verification for in-app purchase?

Tags: iphone, algorithm, security, in-app-purchase

I have developed an iPhone application that was rejected. With this application I offer an SMS transmission service. On my website each user has an account and he can buy credits on the website to be able to send SMS.

The reason for rejections was that my app uses an external service, my website. They say I have to use in-app purchase for the credits.

So now I am about to extend my api. So if purchase takes place in-app the web server needs to know that there was a purchase and what type of purchase. This is done using HTTP-POST.

I could build a simple url and register the purchase in the user-account, since I can verify that an purchase was performed correctly in the app store. But to prevent hacking and just for security reason I think there has to be some kind of encryption.

E.g. if the payment process in the app was successful I send a HTTP-POST to my webserver. It contains some encrypted key that can be encrypted by the webserver.

What do you think about all this? How can I make my api safe regarding in-app purchase and what security algorithm could I use?

Any other suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably look into the [Server Product Model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1), rather than trying to invent some way for your app on the device to tell the server that credit was purchased after the fact. The section on [Verifying Store Receipts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1) will come in handy; in short, your app transmits the contents of `transactionReceipt` to your server (ideally via HTTPS). Your server base64-encodes it, embeds it in a simple JSON object, and posts it to Apple to get the status and verified purchase information.

Answer (score 2):

I have a complete implementation of storekit including the server code.

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/

Try this

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this wiki article on [public key encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_encryption). This is what you'll probably what to be using.

CommonCrypto is a module available for iOS that deals with this type of encryption. Here is a [sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html) in the iOS developer library that uses this module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You are correct. That is the best way. When user purchase credit using In-App purchase(IAP) You will have delegate method for purchase succeed. So you can call your Server API in this delegate method and put some flag with credit number in the user table of your server database. You can send this info encrypted and your server would decrypt it and insert in your database.